# App Engine - getting KeyError with memcache implementation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm trying to implement the code that Guido posted as an answer to the question [Avoiding Memcache 1M limit of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127982/avoiding-memcache-1m-limit-of-values/9143912#9143912).  Everything seems(?) to be working when I first load the page and add values to memcache, but when I re-load it and retrieve values from the memcache I get a strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 194, in Handle
    for chunk in result:
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 1036, in appstats_wsgi_wrapper
    result = app(environ, appstats_start_response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/appengineurlhere/mypythoncode.py", line 87, in get
    entitylist = retrieve("entitylist")
  File "/appengineurlhere/mypythoncode.py", line 53, in retrieve
    return pickle.loads(serialized)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: ':'
```

Here's the store/retrieve code:

```
def store(key, value, chunksize=750000):
    serialized = pickle.dumps(value, 2)
    values = {}
    for i in xrange(0, len(serialized), chunksize):
        values['%s.%s' % (key, i//chunksize)] = serialized[i : i+chunksize]
    memcache.set_multi(values)

def retrieve(key):
    result = memcache.get_multi(['%s.%s' % (key, i) for i in xrange(32)])
    serialized = ''.join([v for v in result.values() if v is not None])
    return pickle.loads(serialized)
```

And this is how I'm using it:

```
try:
  entitylist = retrieve("entitylist")
except EOFError:
  entitylist = MyModel.all().fetch(None)
  store("entitylist", entitylist)
```

Other oddities:

- I don't see this on my development server; just the production App Engine site.  (Though the data on my development server is slightly different; I believe it all fits into the standard 1MB memcache size, where the production data is larger.)
- When I search for "entitylist" on both my development and production admin panel, App Engine tells me "no such key".  Yet based on the total size of the memcache shown (this is the only place I've implemented memcache), it absolutely appears that something is getting cached.

Can anyone please point me in the direction of something I should look at or fix?

Comment: FYI: [the memcache API pickles your data automatically](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_set); does your code work if you use set/get without the pickling?

Comment: Hi, Will.  Because the overall size is greater than 1MB, doing memcache in the regular way falls over.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have some old instances of MyModel that don't match with the current definition of MyModel?  You could get errors while pickling if there are unrecognized or missing attributes.

Comment: Hi, dragonx.  Very interesting; how could I figure out if this was the case?

Comment: Try catching the KeyError and printing the serialized string in the log, then you can take a look at what's going on.