# How to slice the chunk from one variable in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Say, I have a `List<Entity>` to be stored into Google Memcache. But Google Memcache has size limitation to store 1 object, the maximum size is 1MB. But my `List<Entity>` is about 20MB or more. How do I slice them down from `List<Entity>` and reconnect them back into one later?

There is a method to overcome this in Python - [Avoiding Memcache "1000000 bytes in length" limit on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127982/avoiding-memcache-1m-limit-of-values). But I don't find a way to do this in Java. Please help if you know anything to do with this.

Comment: How about storing the single `Entity` objects separately? Are they still bigger than 1MB?

Comment: @Raibaz: Well, by doing that way is not an issue. I am asking how to overcome this matter when the object is more than 1MB size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your `List<Entity>` to a File, and break that file up into multiple files, send the files and put them back together on the receiving end. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/); [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387954/how-to-serialize-a-list-in-java) may also be helpful. You can use [SequenceInputSteam](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) to assist in the deserialization of an object from multiple files.

Comment: Is there a guide to serialize a variable? All I know how to serialize an input stream and an output stream in file format.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that... It seems logic to me.

Comment: No problem.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387954/how-to-serialize-a-list-in-java) may also be helpful.