# Couchbase json field limitation

Tags: php, couchbase

I am posting some large data onto couchbase:

Two scenarios:

1) The data string is very large and the document does not get saved.

```
{
    "abc": "data"
}
```

2) Now if I divide the large data string into multiple parts it gets posted.

```
{
 "abc0": "data1",
 "abc1": "data2"
}
```

Is there a flag I can change or some settings to enable the first scenario?

Comment: Look at [this][1] question, I hope it's help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127982/avoiding-memcache-1m-limit-of-values

Comment: Which means I may have to split the data, is there any documentation on couchbase for this? What do they recommend? Could not find anything

Comment: One more questio, is it possible that the admin console does not show data but the data is actually present - because the console hits a limit?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find this file in directory with couchbase server:

```
documents.js
```

in this file you will see this lines:

```
var DocumentsSection = {
  docsLimit: 1000,
  docBytesLimit: 2500,
...
```

So you can edit this fields.
About you second question... Everything is possible, I dont know:)

**UPDATE**

docsLimit field used in this funtcion:

```
function isJsonOverLimited(json) {
      return getStringBytes(json) > self.docBytesLimit;
    }
```

It's in the same file. You can try return false value instead docBytesLimit, but I dont sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to look at your document storage strategy to solve the problem if your data string is very large. Please see my question: [What is the best document storage strategy in NoSQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772720/what-is-the-best-document-storage-strategy-in-nosql-databases/) and my comments as to how I solved my own problem (in absence of some good answers or good documentation in Couchbase on that question).